# Multiple Select Foreign Key Field Django Form

Tags: python, django

I have a form where I want to display multiple select foreign key field.

**Form.py**

```
class ManagerGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = ['usergroup_group']
```

**Models.py**

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):

    usergroup_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usergroup_group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my form I want to select `usergroup_group` multiple times.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working as expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only save a single object to ForeignKey field if you want to add multiple groups to a single user use a many-to-many field.

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):

   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   group = models.ManyToManyField(Groups)
```

Or

If want same table as you created, you can use Django formsets, Please refer the docs:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Atley…. Atley… Atley…